# Wordpress - make wordpress comments available to external content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently redesigning a website and I have to use a legacy database layout.

Lets say i have items like a book and this book is displayed via an URL like example.com/book/bookid/.

Information about that book is stored in the database and is displayed to the user on that page.  I used the wordpress rewrite engine and the WP_QUERY variable to get the bookid so I can retrieve all the info I want to display from the database. This legacy db is independant from the wordpress DB.

Users should be able to comment on particular books though.

My question is whether there is an elegant way to allow the wordpress comment engine to be used on those book pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always user WordPress's custom post type which is really easy to create.

Just add following code in your functions.php file of your current theme.
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'book',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Books' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Book' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

Now, in the WordPress's admin area, you will be able to see Book Post type where you can add new book which WordPress treats it as post.

to show list of books, add this page
archive-books.php

to show single book details page
single-books.php
on this page, you can add user WordPress' in built comment function.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'walker'            => null,
    'max_depth'         => '',
    'style'             => 'ul',
    'callback'          => null,
    'end-callback'      => null,
    'type'              => 'all',
    'reply_text'        => 'Reply',
    'page'              => '',
    'per_page'          => '',
    'avatar_size'       => 32,
    'reverse_top_level' => null,
    'reverse_children'  => '',
    'format'            => 'html5', // or 'xhtml' if no 'HTML5' theme support
    'short_ping'        => false,   // @since 3.6
        'echo'              => true     // boolean, default is true
); ?>
```

Comment: I did stumble across this solution already, the problem is that I would need to add all books from the legacy DB as a custom post in wordpress.

Comment: Another issue is that i need to keep the already existant permalinks to those books.

Comment: to add all books at once from old database, you can create a separate pages and iterate through them all and create custom post for each programmatically. Won't take much time!

Comment: In WordPress you can use https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule to match old books url into wordpress.

Comment: After doing some more research and testing, this seems to be the way to go. Hence, this is the correct answer. Thank you.